# Transposing per variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just starting out with python and pandas, SO is fantastic for learning.

Have been looking through documentation and tutorials for a few hours, but I think I'm lacking the python vocab to find what I'm after.

I have temperature data (c) logged at consistent times (b) but in different locations (a). I'd like to transpose (*unstack?*) by variable. For example:

```
  a              b             c                  
0001    2016-02-01 00:00    19.93
0001    2016-02-01 00:30    19.5
0001    2016-02-01 01:00    19.25
...
0002    2016-02-01 00:00    23.37
0002    2016-02-01 00:30    22.93
0002    2016-02-01 01:00    22.56
```

to go to:

```
                    0001       0002
2016-02-01 00:00    19.93     23.37
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `pd.pivot_table`

Comment: What's the name of your first column?

Comment: Great, thanks @Kopytok

Comment: @kbbal, its currently named 'valuekey' (int64) - apologies, a & b have shifted to the right in the example

Comment: Your output doesn't match your input data. For example, there is no row with date `2016-02-01 00:00 ` and `a` equals `0002`

Comment: Great spot @RafaelC, in my actual data there is, however, I messed up in the comments. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
['0001',    '2016-02-01 00:00',    19.93],
['0001',    '2016-02-01 00:30',    19.5],
['0001',    '2016-02-01 01:00',    19.25],
['0002',    '2016-02-02 00:00',    23.37],
['0002',    '2016-02-02 00:30',    22.93],
['0002',    '2016-02-02 01:00',    22.56]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['valuekey', 'a', 'b'])

df['a'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').dt.time

df = df.pivot(index = 'a', columns = 'valuekey', values = 'b')

print(df)

#output
valuekey   0001   0002
a                     
00:00:00  19.93  23.37
00:30:00  19.50  22.93
01:00:00  19.25  22.56
```

I assume that your times are in hours and minutes.